# JUNOS set system syntax error

Tags: networking, juniper, junos

I'm trying to enable the web interface on JUNOS 11.4R13.5 (outdated I know)

I'm trying to use the command `set system services web-management https interface`

But I'm unable to run it as I get a syntax error when I attempt to hit space after `system`: `syntax error, expecting <command>`.

Is the `set system` syntax only on newer versions of JUNOS?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I hadn't gone into configure mode (just type `configure`).